# Should I create helper methods in test files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it a good practice to create helper method in test file if this method is specific only to tests in this file?
For example, in:

> test/integration/post_index_test.rb

among some tests i have defined helper method which is applicable only to tests in this file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'some test' do
    this_file_specific_helper_method
  end

  def only_this_file_specific_helper_method
    # method body
  end
end
```

Can I do this, or it should be avoided. If not, where should I put this method. In generic

> test/test_helper.rb

file? Should I create a separate file? Or maybe there is something wrong with my design and I shouldn't have a need for this method at all?

Comment: I hope someone answers this question as I've created an application that basically requires login access to every page (but the login page) for use at my company, and I was wondering if there's someway to write a helper method to just call the login easier.

Comment: You can use before_action filter in yours controllers with helper method that checks if user is logged in and if not redirects to login page. My question is ONLY about test helper methods.

Comment: and so was mine..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use helper methods within your test files. I don't see why not. If the method performs a routine that you will be using many times within that specific test, using a private helper method would be the way to go.